# What exactly causes SSRIs, SNRIs, and tricyclics to induce akathisia?

Tags: pharmacology, medicine, toxicology, medicinal-chemistry

Such as too high neurotransmitter levels (serotonin/dopamine/other) or the method of drug delivery or some other reason?

- Please keep in mind I know very little about this subject, I apologize for the vagueness